# joining two lists together to make a new list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I've searched around on stackoverflow and google, but couldn't find a solution on joining 2 lists together when one of the lists is a 2d array.

```
list1 = [['AA', 'FB', 'BC', 'EA', 'FB'], ['AA', 'AA', 'FB', 'FC', 'DE']]
list2 = ['F', 'I', 'V', 'E', 'S']
```

What I want:

```
list3 = [['F',['AA','AA']],['I',['FB','AA']],['V',['BC','FB']],['E',['EA','FC']],['S',['FB','DE']]]
```

I've tried:

```
    for i in list2:
     print i
     list3.append([list2[i], list1[i][i]])
```

I've also tried doing `list3 = list2.insert(i, list1[i][i])` instead (inside the for loop)

The error I'm getting is 'Type error: list indices must be integers, not str'

Comment: `list3` doesn't look like a list

Comment: The output you want cannot exist. If you mean `['F', ['AA','AA']]`, you could use `zip` to do this (e.g. see `zip(list2, zip(*list1))`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe wrote it out by hand so I missed that.  Thanks for the clarification, and I edited my post so it should be correct

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
>>> list(zip(list2, zip(list1[0], list1[1])))
[('F', ('AA', 'AA')),
 ('I', ('FB', 'AA')), 
 ('V', ('BC', 'FB')), 
 ('E', ('EA', 'FC')), 
 ('S', ('FB', 'DE'))]
```